# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{N/2}(N-2n+1)\cos{(2n-1)x}\geq 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have been plotting and investigating some summations and then trying to prove qualities which they appear to have. One problem I have come across is the sum

$\sum_{n=1}^{N/2}(N-2n+1)\cos{(2n-1)x}$

which I think is positive on the interval $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (and similar observations for other intervals). I am having trouble proving this is the case because of the manipulation of summations (which I am new to) and the oscillation of the cosine terms. Does anyone have any ideas for how to prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{N/2}(N-2n+1)\cos{(2n-1)x}\geq0$

for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$?